# Entity Framework Models are not working after Reverse Engineering. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I tried to use the reverse engineering method as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). I had to do that because of the changes in a few table structures. After this, the models are not recognized as available resources, although the folder structure is the same. This is the folder structure:

```
-Data
--- DBContexts
------ ContextFile.cs
--- Models
------ Entity.cs
```

I ran the following command for the process:

```
Scaffold-DbContext '<connection-string>' Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -contextdir Data/DbContexts -outputdir Data/Models -context ContextFile -Force
```

I had to use the `-Force` flag to overwrite the previous generated models.

I am getting the following error when I try to use the models:
`type or namespace name could not be found.`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide actual code and actual errors or describe what exactly you mean by *not recognized as available resources*. Post as text - **no images**. ,

Comment: Namespace change?

Comment: @CaiusJard I think so

Comment: *I had to use the -Force flag to overwrite the previous generated models.* - do you still have the originals in source control (git) some where? You can scaff to a new folder rather than overwrite and then use a diff tool to see what changes, maybe just patch some changes across or pass a command line parameter for the namespace etc so the new classes match the old. Or even just click on  the red widely line and wait some seconds for the lightbulb menu to appear - it should have suggestions for adding a `using` so the new namespaces are imported

Comment: It says to use `using ....Data.Models` instead of `using ...Models`. I wanted to know why this difference occurs given the models were previously also in the `Data/Models` folder